# How can I turn on the Intel HD manually?

Tags: macbook-pro, snow-leopard, graphics

For some weeks my MacBook 6.2 does not switch to the integrated graphics adapter (Intel HD). This is especially crucial when I work on battery (which happens quite often). I guess the runtime could be enhanced when it would take the HD adapter for display.

I checked that it automatically changes the graphics mode. I am running Snow Leopard 10.6.8.

I recently installed 8GiB RAM (not from Apple). Could this probably related to this issue? Actually I do not want to downgrade or use the expensive Apple RAM.

So, how can I manually turn on the internal graphics adapter?

Answer (score 3):

[gfxCardStatus](http://gfx.io) will let you choose which *Graphic Card* to use. It has three modes:

- **Dynamic Switching**: An alias for the built-in automatic graphics switching feature in OS X.
- **Integrated Only**: Forces the more battery-friendly graphics on and disallows automatic switching.
- **Discrete Only**: Forces the more power-hungry graphics on and disallows automatic switching.

Comment: Seems quite nice, but sadly I can't use it due to Snow-Leopard 10.6.8. But I found in the source code, where the line probably has to be changed. I'll give it a try.

Comment: gfxCardStatus **v1.7** (v2.3 now) did work for Snow Leopard. Perhaps downloading the code from gitHub and rolling back to that version might do the trick.